# Stop UITextView From Scrolling Parent UITableView

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview, uitextview

So I've put a UITextView in a UITableView for the separators and to make it so I don't have to do a bunch of resizing based on the size of the screen and what not. The only problem is that when the user taps on the text view, it scrolls the tableview so that the lowest line with no text is at the top. If there is anything inside it, it scrolls right past it. I haven't found any documentation on why this happens or how to stop it. If anyone could provide any input or tips, that would be appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: What do you mean by using `UITextView` for the separators? I don't get what's your setup nor what you are trying to achieve. Some code and/or screenshots would help.

Comment: @RicardoSánchez-Sáez In one of the WWDC sessions, Apple said to use UITableViews for separators between different elements, as most of them don't have borders anymore. I've just dragged a UITextView into a cell in a static UITableView.